# How to Properly Get Remote IP Address in a Blazor-Server Application?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, httpcontext

I've looked around and a few questions exactly like this has been answered already however they all state the solution as what I'm currently trying to do which it STILL doesn't work...
Currently, I am using a Blazor-Server app that has this line on the program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And on my one of my pages, I have this code to try and get the remote IP address of this connection:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor context;
context.HttpContext?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString()
```

On my local machiene testing it returns **127.0.0.1**, however when I actually host the website with IIS, the **context.HttpContext** is actually **null**. I'm curious what is the simplest and yet effective way to get the remote IP address of the user on the website then if this will not work?

Thanks!

Comment: HttpContext  would only be accrssed in prerender or your component is in static

Comment: @daniherrera so if you notice my original post of code, I did this exactly and it still shows that the HttpContext object is null.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I do have prerended on, yet the HttpContext object is still null.

Comment: @daniherrera Place in the `App.razor` file as well and yet it is still null.

Comment: @therehere3, you are right, no way through HttpContext. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried `[CascadingParameter] public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;`
to no avail. There seems to be no way to get the client's IP?

Comment: @Sasino yeah I think there is no way to get the client's IP which I feel like is a HUGE oversight... :/

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
   options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Add this piece of code in your `program.cs` this will enable forwarded headers

**or**

```
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
       var ip = ip.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I apprecaite that comment and was very excited to see if this fixed it! However, it still says that the `context.HttpContext` object is null :(

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me when I insert it in host.cshtml file

```
 string? ip = HttpContext.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```